# Make deleting by url not possible. Only by direct button click

Tags: python, django

I have a model form editing template with Save and Delete buttons. 
I check in the view that the user who tries to delete a post is the owner of it. I use a pop up onlick confirmation.

But if I just go to the url `(.../post_delete/pk)` it deletes the post right away.
How do I make sure the deletion is only possible with a button click on the edit template?

Comment: You should only process the delete on a POST request.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, could you please show an example how it should look?

Comment: @Alina use a form with "POST" as method attribute and restrict your view to `POST` requests with the `require_POST` decorator. And by all means READ THE HTTP RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231

Comment: You can also look into using the generic [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) which should handle the deletion upon `POST`...

Comment: @BernhardVallant i was trying to not use the DeleteView with a separate template to confirm the deletion.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers disregarding the rude comment, thanks for answer

Comment: @Alina you can still use the `DeleteView` as the confirm template will only show for a `GET` request.  Just do a `POST` request to the url of the `DeleteView` and you should be fine!

Comment: @Alina advising you to read the HTTP rcf is not "rude" in any way, it's the most useful and friendly advice anyone could give you given your question.

Comment: @BernhardVallant thank you! I also have an other button on the edit template which changes the status of the post (also with onlick confirm) and I have the same problem as with delete button. how would i do it properly?

Comment: @Alina you need a `<form method="post" action="url to delete view"><button type="submit" /></form>` which will send the post request to the delete view (I assume you use a link insted)